# Using s3:GetObject from KMS encrypted Bucket with an Alias

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, devops, amazon-iam, amazon-kms

I am trying to use KMS Key Alias to get objects from S3 which is not working while put objects is working with same policy. My policy looks like below

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowListBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::primary-db-backups-XXXXX"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowGetPutPostgresBackups",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::primary-db-backups-XXXXX/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowS3KMS",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
                "kms:Decrypt"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "kms:RequestAlias": "alias/infra_s3_key"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The error I am getting is

```
download failed: s3://primary-db-backups-XXXXX/ip15000_2021-10-19T02-37-52.sql to - An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied
```

If I put KMS Key ARN in Resource then it works. I am not sure why GetObject is not working while PutObjects works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably happens because S3 is calling **KMS key by its ARN**, not `alias`. You could use `alias/infra_s3_key` only if the API call to KMS made by S3 would be itself using `alias/infra_s3_key`. But its probably using key ARN, thus only condition with the KMS key ARN works.